# Implementing EventProcessingConfigurer,registerErrorHandler to properly handle @EventHandler errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am trying to add a ErrorHandler via the EventProcessingConfigurer.registerErrorHandler() method and while it is showing on the configuration the class itself is not being called.

Am currently using Axon 4.1.1 (With out Axon server) and Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE.

i have based my code off [github/AxonFramework](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/config/src/test/java/org/axonframework/config/EventProcessingModuleTest.java#L399) but it isn't acting the same.

Config:

```java
@Autowired
public void configure(final EventProcessingConfigurer config) {
    TestErrorHandler testErrorHandler = new TestErrorHandler();
    config.registerErrorHandler("SolrProjection", configuration -> testErrorHandler);
}
```

ErrorHander:

```java
public class TestErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler, ListenerInvocationErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleError(final ErrorContext errorContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TestErrorHandler.handleError()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Exception exception, final EventMessage<?> event, final EventMessageHandler eventHandler) {
        System.out.println("TestErrorHandler.onError()");
    }
}
```

Projection:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ProcessingGroup("SolrProjection")
public class SolrProjection {
    @EventHandler
    public void onEvent(final TestEvent event,
                        @SequenceNumber Long sequenceNumber,
                        @Timestamp final Instant requestTimestamp,
                        @MessageIdentifier final String messageIdentifier,
                        final MetaData metaData) {
        if (true) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
```

even thou i am directly throwing an error, i do not ever see the two system.out's in console. and putting log statements in the @EventHandler are properly being called.

Comment: For the as of now current Axon version 4.5 the link is https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/4.5/axon-framework/events/event-processors#exceptions-raised-by-event-handler-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ErrorHandler` is tasked to dealing with different exceptions than what you expect.
When it comes to handling events, Axon Framework deduces two layers:

1. The internal `EventProcessor` layer
2. The Event Handling Components written by framework users

Exceptions thrown within the `EventProcessor` are dealt with by the `ErrorHandler` you've configured.
For customizing the process for handling exceptions from your own Event Handlers, you 
will have to configure the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`.

To configure a general/default `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`, you can use the following method in your first snippet:

```
EventProcessingConfigurer#registerDefaultListenerInvocationErrorHandler(
        Function<Configuration, ListenerInvocationErrorHandler>
)
```

You can also check out Axon's Reference Guide at [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#exceptions-raised-by-event-handler-methods) page for more info on this.
Hope this helps you out @sherring!

Comment: Thanks again Steven, i was mis-reading (again) and makes sense that "registerListenerInvocationErrorHandler" is what i should have been doing instead of the framework level. i changed to use that in my config and it is indeed getting into that method to show that its catching said exception.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped @sherring! And, misreading something can happen to the best right? That's also why there are fora like these if you ask.

Comment: Hi @steven , do you have an example of this configuration for Axon 2.4?

Comment: As my Axon 2 days are about 7 years behind me, I had to look this up in the reference guide. I'd suggest to do the same on your part if you need to know specifics on the matter. Definitely a lot of the current future in Axon 4 (and 3 for that matter) **are not** present in Axon 2. I'd thus highly recommend to upgrade to a more recent version of the framework @caytekin. Regardless, this piece of the ref-guide talks a bit about Error Handling for Clusters (i.e. currently called EventProcessors) in Axon 2 -> https://legacy-docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/2.4/event-processing.html#d5e1705